# Mapbox white borders around map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I've designed a Mapbox map and I am displaying it using Javascript. There seems to be a white border around the map when it's being dragged, how do I get rid of this?
I'd like to block it off so that it's not possible to drag into the white area... thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8MM9.png

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the map in a div. Based off the pic it looks like you need to style it to make it fill in correctly. I can't be sure without code.

Definitely check out the examples https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.2/  and also checkout Mapbox Studio for map specific styling options. https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/#linux

In the examples they style in page using a style tag. I suggested moving that to its own stylesheet. If you want to avoid CSS all together, check out leaflet. Mapbox was built off it and they work together. http://leafletjs.com/
This allows you to give it a class/id and change it's size. Here is a basic map example:

A simple map
Initializing a Map in an HTML element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>A simple map</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.2/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.2/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86nkdio')
    .setView([40, -74.50], 9);
</script>
</body>
</html
```

>

Some CSS for size: Check out http://www.w3schools.com/css/ for more information on sizing elements.

```
#map {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
```